# Significance of the generic pull_request event and other more specific pull_request events like pull_request.opened

Tags: github, github-api, probot, github-app

I am developing a **GitHub App** using **nodejs** and **probot** framework. I can see the **Application** class (https://probot.github.io/api/latest/classes/application.html) of the  probot framework contains events like :

```
> event: "pull_request" | "pull_request.assigned" |
> "pull_request.closed" | "pull_request.edited" | "pull_request.labeled"
> | "pull_request.opened" | "pull_request.reopened" |
> "pull_request.review_request_removed" |
> "pull_request.review_requested" | "pull_request.unassigned" |
> "pull_request.unlabeled" | "pull_request.synchronize
```

I have noticed that when the **"Create pull request"** button is clicked, then the **pull_request** as well as **pull_request.opened** events are fired.

In order to understand this behavior of **firing multiple seemingly similar events upon the click of the same button**, I tried to reopen a closed request and print out the Context object for both **pull_request** event as well as **pull_request.reopened** event.

I did a diff comparison of both the contexts and  found that the contexts returned by both the events are 
identical except that the context of **pull_request** event contained below **additional** properties :

```
merged: false,
        mergeable: null,
        rebaseable: null,
        mergeable_state: 'unknown',
        merged_by: null,
        comments: 6,
        review_comments: 0,
        maintainer_can_modify: false,
        commits: 1,
        additions: 1,
        deletions: 0,
        changed_files: 1 },
     repository:
      { id: 123456789,
        node_id: '',
        name: '',
        full_name: '',
        private: true,
        owner: [Object],
        html_url: 'some-url-here'
        .
        .
        ///////////////////--------many more urls-------//////////////////////
        created_at: '2020-04-0',
        updated_at: '2020-04-0',
```

We know that the general format of the context object returned is as follows :

```
Context {
  name: 'pull_request',
  id: '187128937812-8219-89891892133-16752-1234576765545',
  payload:
   { action: 'reopened',
     number: 1,
     pull_request:
      { url:
        .
        .
        .and so on.......
```

This above information is present in both the contexts. We can see that this also tells us about the specific action that was performed and this is denoted by the **context.payload.action**. So, if someone's requirement is to get hold of the **pull_request.opened** he/she could do it by just by using **pull_request** event as follows :

```
app.on('pull_request', async context => {
    console.log('---------------------- on pull_request event')
    console.log('Context returned :----', context)
  })
```

And doesn't need to care about the other more specific events(here **pull_request.opened**) i.e. apart from what is achieved from the above code, below code would provide no real additional help :

```
app.on('pull_request.opened', async context => {
    console.log('---------------------- on pull_request.opened')
    console.log('Context returned :----', context)
  })
```

So here is the question that's troubling me :
What is the purpose of the **pull_request** event , if its other specific forms (like **pull_request.reopened**) carry no different information(more precisely, if their contexts contain no different infos) ?

I am quite sure that there does lie some wisdom behind it. I'm not able to find anything on the internet, nothing in the docs that could explain this.

Please help me understand the hidden wisdom.

**EDIT 1 : START**

Forgot to mention one observation and that is : Reopening the pull request also triggers **issue_comment.created** event.  So, So three events are triggered by one action(clicking **Create Pull Request**).

**EDIT 2 : START**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the **pull_request** event , if its other specific forms (like **pull_request.reopened**) carry no different information(more precisely, if their contexts contain no different infos) ?

This is just a feature of Probot to simplify processing webhook events from GitHub. I'll try and explain why it's helpful.

If you were to consume webhook events without Probot, you would have to parse every `pull_request` event, check the `action` field for a case, and decide whether to handle it.

There are several events that have a top-level `action` field in the payload, incuding:

- [`check_run`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#checkrunevent)
- [`issue`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuesevent)
- [`project`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#projectevent)
- [`pull_request`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent)
- and many more [in the docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/)...

Rather than make application developers perform this parsing and inspection of the JSON themselves they decided to simplify the callbacks so you can subscribe to webhooks using the specific `[event].[action]` pattern, and the framework takes care of invoking your callback when the matching event and action is received.

So you have two options for handling `pull_request` events:

- if you don't know which events you need, or need to dynamically process events, subscribing to `pull_request` is how you would receive all pull request events
- if you know which events you should handle, and can ignore the rest, subscribe to explicit `pull_request.[event]` should simplify your application code

You could also subscribe to `*`, which represents all events the probot app receives, rather than explicitly listing all supported events in your app.

Comment: thanks a lot for this nice explanation. So we can safely assume that there are no additional benefits apart from what you mentioned i.e. parsing. I am just concerned which approach is better in terms of performance, using the event.action or just the events and then parsing based on action.

Comment: The framework emits events for both `event` and `event.action`, so only subscribe to the event (or events) that you care about in your application code https://github.com/probot/probot/blob/9265609c91f4b76282c281bdef787d684cf2c5bf/src/application.ts#L73-L79